# Trying to pass function as parameter to another function in C++, not getting it?

Tags: c++

please guide me in following regards, i am new to c++. Here i am just practicing Class in C++. While writing an example program, i have just tried to change it a bit and pass function as a parameter to another function.

But i think in due process i am missing some thing....please guide me...Thanks to all
     #include

```
 using namespace std;

 class my_class{

             int i;
             int j;
         public:
             int RealNumber(int a, int b);
             void WriteAns(int c);
 };

 int RealNumber(int a, int b)
 {
     return a+b;
 }
 void WriteAns(int c)
 {
     int i =  c;
     cout<<"Added numbers are: "<<i<<endl;
 }


int main()
{

     int j =10, k=20;
    int m = 0;


    m = RealNumber(j,k);

     /*I have tried to pass the function RealNumber in place of m,
      while declaring the function as follow:

       WriteAns(int *c);

      and then i have tried to pass function RealNumber as a parameter

      WriteAns(&RealNumber(j,k));

      */

      WriteAns(m);   //By passing m i get the correct ans


      return 0;
```

}

Comment: This is very difficult to follow. You want to pass the function to `WriteAns` but `WriteAns` does not take a function as the argument. If you want to pass the result of the function, just use `WriteAns(RealNumber(j, k));`

Comment: You _can_ pass a function, but it is slightly more complicated.  See:  http://ideone.com/tvjPN7

Comment: "and pass function as a parameter to another function" or "and pass ***the results of a*** function as a parameter to another function"? These are quite different concepts. I suspect you mean the latter.

Answer (score 4):

This is a very minor mistake; you are not trying to pass the actual function as a parameter (as you have implemented) but you are merely trying to pass the reulst of the function.
change `&RealNumber(j,k)` to `RealNumber(j,k)` and it should work

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `&` on an rvalue. The value returned by `RealNumber` is a temporary, and by extension an rvalue, so `&RealNumber(a, b)` is invalid. Like the error says, you need an lvalue. Try this instead:

```
 void WriteAns(int* c)
 {
     cout<<"Added numbers are: "<<*c<<endl;
 }
 int c = RealNumber(j,k)
 WriteAns(&c);
```

---

Reference: [Value Categories](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category)

rvalue (until C++11) / prvalue (since C++11)

> A prvalue ("pure" rvalue) is an expression that identifies a temporary
>   object (or a subobject thereof) or is a value not associated with any
>   object.
>
> The following expressions are prvalues:
>
> - Function call/operator expression if the function's or the operator's    return type is not a reference, such as str.substr(1, 2)
>     or 2+2

Answer (score 0):

If You are trying to pass "function Return value as parameter" , then solution given by Chad  should work.

If You are trying to pass "function as parameter" as mentioned above ( pass function as a parameter to another function.),  then you need to change signature of WriteAns to receive Function pointer.

```
void WriteAns(int  (*fp)(int,int))
{
  int i =  (*funcp)(10,20);
  cout<<"Added numbers are: "<<i<<endl;
}

WriteAns(&RealNumber(j,k));
```